# I want to stuff my wallet and pockets full of bells, what's the maximum amount of cash that I can carry?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I want to carry the most amount of bells absolutely possible. I can fit money in my wallet and it looks like I can carry sacks of cash as well. I'm not sure what the limits are though.

How many bells can I carry?

Answer (score 10):

This answer is assuming you've upgraded your pockets to the max.

---

This is what your wallet and pockets will look like maxed out with bells:

[image]

- You can carry 40 sacks of bells at 99,000 bells each.
- You can carry 99,999 bells in your wallet.
- Altogether you can carry 4,059,999 bells.

Alternatively you can click "Full Amount" on your ABD withdrawal page, like this:

[image]

Where it will also prompt you to take out the maximum amount of: 4,059,999 bells.